# longest common sequence instead of word

Tags: python, string, longest-substring

i am using a list and iterating from last to first element of the strings to find the longest common sub word between them. So the value for the current iteration(LC[i][j]) will depend both on the previous iteration LC[i+1][j+1] and the current matching of the element,

I am facing two issues. - the else statement LC[i][j] = 0 is forcing the element of LC[i+1][j+1] = 0, so if there is a match in the current iteration then LC[i][j] is becoming 1(because LC[i+1][j+1] has been overwritten to 0. - on removing the else statement instead of finding longest common word it is giving longest common sub sequence. please see the output for both the cases

```
case 1. when else is present. 
1st str: zxab enter 2nd str: yzab 
i = 3 j = 3 LC[i][j] = 1 LC[i+1][j+1] = 0 
i = 2 j = 2 LC[i][j] = 1 LC[i+1][j+1] = 0 
i = 0 j = 1 LC[i][j] = 1 LC[i+1][j+1] = 0 
max len = 1



case 2. else block removed.
i = 3 j = 3 LC[i][j] = 1 LC[i+1][j+1] = 0 
i = 2 j = 2 LC[i][j] = 2 LC[i+1][j+1] = 1
i = 0 j = 1 LC[i][j] = 3 LC[i+1][j+1] = 2 

max len = 3
correct answer for max_len should have been 2.



def LCW(u,v):
    m = len(u)
    n = len(v)

    LC = [[0] * (len(v) + 1)] * (len(u) + 1)  # create the table one extra due to denote the endng of the word

    max_len = 0

    for i in range(m-1,-1,-1):    # because the strng's last elemnt can be accessed by range(m) == m-1
        for j in range(n-1,-1,-1):
            if u[i] == v[j]:
                LC[i][j] = 1 + LC[i+1][j+1]

            #else: LC[i][j] = 0
            if max_len < LC[i][j]:
                max_len = LC[i][j]
    return max_len
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input, output, and expected output?

Comment: i am using a list and iterating from last to first element of the strings to find the longest common sub word between them. So the value for the current iteration(LC[i][j]) will depend both on the previous iteration LC[i+1][j+1] and the current matching of the element.

Comment: I am facing two issues. 
- the else statement LC[i][j] = 0 is forcing the element of LC[i+1][j+1] = 0, so  if there is a match in the current iteration then LC[i][j] is becoming 1(because LC[i+1][j+1] has been overwritten to 0.  
- on removing the else statement instead of finding longest common word it is giving longest common sub sequence. please see the output for both the cases.

Comment: case 1. when else is present.
enter 1st str: zxab
enter 2nd str: yzab

i =  3 j =  3 LC[i][j] =  1 LC[i+1][j+1] =  0
i =  2 j =  2 LC[i][j] =  1 LC[i+1][j+1] =  0
i =  0 j =  1 LC[i][j] =  1 LC[i+1][j+1] =  0
max len = 1

case 2. else block removed.

i =  3 j =  3 LC[i][j] =  1 LC[i+1][j+1] =  0
i =  2 j =  2 LC[i][j] =  2 LC[i+1][j+1] =  1
i =  0 j =  1 LC[i][j] =  3 LC[i+1][j+1] =  2
max len = 3

Comment: was getting error due to code block when writing the explanation along with it. hence wrote in comments.

Comment: So you're trying to find the longest shared substring between `u` and `v`?

Comment: You still haven't provided an example of input and expected output. Also, you included the tag "dynamic-programming", even though this problem is not an example of dynamic programming.

Comment: yes. sub word not the sub sequence

Comment: case 1. when else is present. enter 1st str: zxab enter 2nd str: yzab i = 3 j = 3 LC[i][j] = 1 LC[i+1][j+1] = 0 i = 2 j = 2 LC[i][j] = 1 LC[i+1][j+1] = 0 i = 0 j = 1 LC[i][j] = 1 LC[i+1][j+1] = 0 max len = 1 case 2. else block removed. i = 3 j = 3 LC[i][j] = 1 LC[i+1][j+1] = 0 i = 2 j = 2 LC[i][j] = 2 LC[i+1][j+1] = 1 i = 0 j = 1 LC[i][j] = 3 LC[i+1][j+1] = 2 max len = 3

Comment: It would be best to edit your question to make your test case more readable.

Comment: updated the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I think you get lost in your 2 dimensional list, which is not needed. You could just use the `in` operator which states either a string can be found in another one. Then the only problem is to create all the sub-strings of one of your inputs.

```
def sliding_window(seq, width):
    """yields all substrings of `seq` of length `width`"""
    return (seq[idx:idx+width] for idx in range(len(seq)-width+1))

def lcw(seq1, seq2):
    """length of the longest common sequence shared by seq1 and seq2"""
    max_width = min(len(seq1), len(seq2))
    for width in range(max_width, 0, -1):
        if any(sub in seq1 for sub in sliding_window(seq2, width)):
            return width
    return 0

lcw('zxab', 'yzab')
>>>
2
```

But it very well might be that I didn't get your definition sub word, which I could not really distinguish from sub sequence.